# Mapping on a image programmatically

Tags: android

Client given me a particular area map image. Here I need to get the longitude and latitude of the location at the Touch point on the image.

Is there any way I can work on this issue. To get the location of touch point on the image programmatically.

Comment: I don't know what format the 'image' is in, but unless it comes with some other data to associate say the top left and bottom right corners with latitude/longitude, then it's impossible.

Comment: No way to do it just with an image, I would consider integrating what you want to do with a MapView.

Comment: Yes, I can figure out latitude and longitude values of location at the top, left and bottom right corners using Google maps or some other sites and take that values as default. If i am having those values how i can work further..... Please let me know. By the way it's a png image.  thankyou

Comment: @blindstuff, How i get integrate image with a Mapview. Please let me know. thanks

Comment: Please give me any ideas on it.........

Comment: NickT answered what I would have suggested, use his answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can really only do this with any accuracy on a MapView, where you can use the methods

```
GeoPoint fromPixels(int x,
                    int y)
Create a new GeoPoint from pixel coordinates relative to the top-left 
of the MapView that provided this PixelConverter.
```

and

```
toPixels
android.graphics.Point toPixels(GeoPoint in,
                                android.graphics.Point out)
Converts the given GeoPoint to onscreen pixel coordinates, relative to 
the top-left of the MapView that provided this Projection.
```

to transform lat/on to screen coordinates.

If it's a plain old .png the, as long as the view covers a *small area* (a few square miles only), you could interpolate the lat/lon at the corners to get an *approximate* value for the touch point. If it was a whole country, then you would have to apply a coordinate transformation to map from a flat Mercator projection to a curved surface.